# Calling Flysystem, why do I get PHP Fatal error: Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local' not found?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, flysystem

I try to run Flysystem's basic example code for the `Local` adapter and get a `Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local' not found` error.  This is my process:

version check:

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2018 21:59:47)
```

install Flysystem:

```
composer require league/flysystem
```

output shows I'm up-to-date (this is my 2nd time running it):

```
Using version ^1.0 for league/flysystem
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

now there's a `vendor` folder in web root.  And within `./web/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter$` are these files:

```
AbstractAdapter.php
AbstractFtpAdapter.php
CanOverwriteFiles.php
Ftpd.php
Ftp.php
Local.php
NullAdapter.php
Polyfill/
SynologyFtp.php
```

...just showing that it seems to be installed correctly(?)  I create one test file and one test directory in my web root:

1. fly-local.php
2. myfiles/

Into `fly-local.php` I paste the text from their docs (https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/local/):

```
<?php

use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;

$adapter = new League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local(__DIR__.'/myfiles');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

...and change the adapter's root folder to `myfiles` (is that correct?).  Then I run it:

```
php fly-local.php
```

It outputs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local' not found in /[PROJECT DIR]/web/fly-local.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /[PROJECT DIR]/web/fly-local.php:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't included composer autoloader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used composer, then you need to include the composer `autoload.php` file.

The `fly-local.php` should be:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;

$adapter = new League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local(__DIR__.'/myfiles');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

If you use a framework, you can see it includes the autoload php file for you (index.php, in general). If your test/custom file is not included to framework, you need to include the file manually.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't mention this but I'm ultimately trying to call it from a Codeigniter 2 model.  So I had to require it like `require_once ('./vendor/autoload.php');` which works.